# Remove HDD while the computer is shutdown but sitll plugged in

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, shutdown, hibernate

I have 2 internal HDDs and it happens a lot that I need to unplug one of them or swap the SATA cables to make one or the other 'Master'.
what I do now is shutdown/hibernate and unplug the power cord completely, can I just shutdown/hibernate and keep it plugged in?
I don't think there's power in the HDDs, but I just want to make sure I won't damage anything

Note: "Windows-7" tag (My OS) was among suggested tags, but I didn't think it's relevant. Should I add it?

Comment: You can shutdown.  If you hibernate you will cause problems.  If your using `Windows 7` then you should tag the question as being relevant to `Windows 7`

Comment: As long as you shutdown window then yes, hibernation NO.  Done it many times.

Answer (score 1):

Unplug the power source from the computer and ground yourself out. Your OS really isn't important. Just because the computer is off doesn't mean there is no power running to it, although usually keeping the power source connected usually wont hurt anything it's not worth the risk. Unplug the power cord from the wall or computer